# Cannot save ISO String as a filename due to colons

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this code which I need to save the result as a filename:

```
let date = new Date();
date.toISOString(); // for example: "2022-12-19T15:28:46.493Z"
```

final string would like like this:

```
let finalStringToSave: "test_2022-12-19T15:28:46.493Z.txt"
```

When I try to save this string I get an error ...cannot save file.

I have the feeling that this is due to the colons ":" as they are not allowed in a filename.

I've tried to replace all the colons to underscore "_" or dash "-" and I tried this:

```
let str = finalStringToSave.replace(/:\s*/g, "-"); 
console.log(str);
```

But for some reason it's not doing the replace.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How can you tell it's "not doing the replace"?

Comment: "*But for some reason it's not doing the replace.*" [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/bupuqadovo/edit?js,console)

Comment: Because I then console.log the str value and the colons are still there

Comment: Unless there's a way to avoid the time having colon's and have some other character in between?

Comment: "*Because I then console.log the str value and the colons are still there*" I've demonstrated that's not the case with the code you shared here. If the code you have produces different result, then it must be different code or otherwise something we cannot know. We are not mind readers, clairvoyants or other types of seers around here. We can only work with the information you've supplied. And it doesn't match what you say happens.

Comment: I've updated the code variable names

Comment: If `let finalStringToSave: "test_2022-12-19T15:28:46.493Z.txt"` is `let finalStringToSave = "test_2022-12-19T15:28:46.493Z.txt"` then [I still cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/julutipiva/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
`test_${date.toISOString()}.txt`.replace(/:/g,"_")
```

Windows seems to have problems saving filenames that contain a ":".
The code above replaces every ":" with an "_".

The regex works like this:

- `/:` selects the ":" in the string
- `/g` is used that all ":" gets replaced, not just the first one

Let me know if it helped.